# Div to appear after another absolute positioned div, not underneath

Tags: html, css

I realise there are other questions on this topic but I can't seem to get those to work.

I have a div within another div. This inner div extends beyond it's container div using absolute position.
The div that comes next `<div class="text">` falls behind the absolute positioned div. I would like it to come after so it, so it is visible.

You can see in this fiddle the `.text` class is being blocked by the absolute positioned `.child` class: **http://jsfiddle.net/0m8aynta/2/**

The height of the absolute positioned div varies so I cannot just set a margin-top to `<div class="text">`

I am open to any suggestions to achieve this but I don't want to use javascript.

Below is the code but take a look at the fiddle.

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Test page</h1>
    <div class="child">
      <div class="inner">testing to see if it can expand beyond its parent</div>
    </div>
  <div class="text">lorem ipsum doodle day yo</div>
</div>

.container {
    width:600px;
    height:600px;
    background:yellow;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:1em;
}
.child {
    background:red;
    padding:1em;
    margin: 0 -500%; 
    padding: 0.5em 500%;
}
.inner {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:600px;
}
```

- **Using**   `margin: 0 -500%; padding: 0.5em 500%;` **it is possible: http://jsfiddle.net/0m8aynta/9/**

Comment: If all you want is a full width div, just close the container and open a new one after the full width div. - http://jsfiddle.net/0m8aynta/3/

Comment: [**Full Width Browser Bars**](http://css-tricks.com/full-browser-width-bars/)

Comment: @SalmanA There are many solutions, I have already suggested two.

Comment: My bad, I was looking at the question, not the intent.

Comment: @Paulie_D Full Width Browser Bars solved it, thanks. I should have seen that before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `-margin` and add `+padding`

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  background: yellow;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1em;
}
.child {
  background: red;
  padding: 1em;
  margin-left: -24px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 24px;
}
.inner {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 600px;
}
```

```html
test
<div class="container">
  <h1>Test page</h1>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="inner">testing to see if it can expand beyond its parent</div>
  </div>
  <p>lorem ipsum doodle day yo</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking Paulie_D's suggestion, simply close the `.container` div and then place the `.text` div:

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0m8aynta/6/)**

**HTML:**

```
test
<div class="container">
    <h1>Test page</h1>
    <div class="child">
        <div class="inner">testing to see if it can expand beyond its parent</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="text">lorem ipsum doodle day yo</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    width:600px;
    height:600px;
    background:yellow;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:1em;
}
.child {
    background:red;
    padding:1em;
    position: absolute;
    right:0;
    left:0;
}
.inner {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:600px;
}
```